# Log color bar/meta data in PGFPLOT

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to create a 2D plot with a color map using pgfplots.  I've managed to get the overall behaviour that I want, but I would like the color map to be logarithmic, rather than linear.  The best I have managed is to use the meta expr key, but then the color bar shows 1-4 instead of 10^1 through 10^4.  Below is my working example.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[colorbar,
xlabel = create energy (keV),
ylabel = deposit energy (kev),
]
\pgfplotstableread{../endep_log_au_30_0_0.csv}\mytable %
\addplot+[scatter, only marks, scatter src=explicit, mark=square]
 table[x=createEn,y=depEn,meta expr=ln(\thisrow{tot})/ln(10)] {\mytable};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way to modify how the labels appear on the colorbar or set it to be logarithmic?  Is there a different way I should be approaching this problem?

(Unfortunately I cannot post an image as a new user)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! It would be good if you could add full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that people can cut and paste to try out the code. In your case, the preamble and `\endep_log_au_30_0_0.csv` are missing, which makes it harder to help with solving the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `meta expr` approach is a good one. In order to get the labels on the colorbar right, you can set `\yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{10^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` for the colorbar -- colorbars are full `axis` environments, so they have all the options available to "normal" plots. You can set the options for the colorbar using `colorbar style={<options>}`:

[image: pgfplots with logarithmic colorbar]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

% Define new pgfmath function for the logarithm to base 10 that also works with fpu library
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}%
}

\pgfplotstableread{
createEn depEn tot
0 5 1
0.1 20 10
0.5 100 100
2 10300 1000
}\mytable %


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
    xlabel = create energy (keV),
    ylabel = deposit energy (keV),
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{10^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult}
]

\addplot+[scatter, only marks, scatter src=explicit, mark=square]
 table[meta expr=lg10(\thisrow{tot})] {\mytable};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Sorry I didn't simplify my data, like in your example (my file is large).  I haven't learned to work with pgfmath yet, so the declare function is very helpful as well.

Comment: side note: `\pgrpathparse` has a range limit, so the above will not work for large (e.g `1e6` *dimension too large*) or small values (e.g. `1e-6`). In this case I found it convenient to use: `colorbar style={yticklabel=$10^{\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult}$}`